# How to get a cell's name in Excel in java using POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am trying to learn POI and I have a sample code.

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class ExpressionExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");
        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper()
                .createFormulaEvaluator();
        HSSFCell formulaCell = (HSSFCell) row.createCell(6);
        HSSFCell c1 = (HSSFCell) row.createCell(1);
        HSSFCell c2 = (HSSFCell) row.createCell(2);
        c1.setCellValue(5);
        c2.setCellValue(10);
        CellReference cr1 = new CellReference(0 , 1); 

        String line = "if(A1>A2, \"LAR\" , if(5>10, \"AB\" , \"CD\"))";
        formulaCell.setCellFormula(line);

        CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(formulaCell);
        System.out.println(cellValue.getStringValue());
    }

}
```

now in my formula I have applied values of cells A1 and A2, but I want to give this value based on my code and cells should be 'C1 and c2. any Idea how to do this ?

It would be great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I have picked up your question correctly but here goes...

If you are wanting to use the values to which you are setting into the cells `c1` and `c2` (in this case '5' & '10') in your formula, you can create 2 `int` objects to hold these values:

```
int c1Value = 5;
int c2Value = 10;
```

You can then use these objects to set the cell values and also include them in your formula:

```
c1.setCellValue(c1Value); 
c2.setCellValue(c2Value);

String line = "if(" + c1Value + ">" + c2Value + ", \"LAR\" , if(5>10, \"AB\" , \"CD\"))";
```

Also note, in your code `c1` refers to the cell `A2` in Excel, and `c2` refers to cell `A3`. Both rows and columns start at 0 in Apache.

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: I got it .. We can use cellReference. I was supposed to get expression as input.